# funciones en nodejs con callbacks

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estuve siguiendo un tutorial y encontre un ejemplo con promesas lo cual es el siguiente:

```js
function requestName(userName){
 
 const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${userName}`;
 fetch(url)
  .then( function(res){
   return res.json(); 
  })
  .then( function(json){
   console.log(json.name);
  })
  .catch( function(e){
   console.log(`El error es: ${e}`);
  });
  
}
```

Aun estoy aprendiendo sobre funciones pero estaba tratando de hacer la misma función con Callback pero el resultado no me imprime nada en la consola o quiza este haciendo algo mal, el codigo es el siguiente:

```js
function requestName(userName){
 const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${userName}`;
 fetch(url, function(err,res){
  if(err){
   console.log(`El error es: ${err}`);
  }else{
   const json = res.json();
   console.log(json);
  }
 })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si bien lo que indica @PabloLozano es correcto, yo tengo una visión diferente de tu pregunta, porque tal vez la entiendo de otro modo. Y es que entiendo que deseas crear una función llamada `requestName`, a la cual le puedas pasar una función [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

Vamos a definir una función `callback` que realizará las tareas correspondientes cuando se reciba una respuesta del servidor.

```js
const showResponse = function(err, response) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(`El error es ${err}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(response);
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos una función `callback` que podremos usar en nuestra función `requestName` de la siguiente forma:

```js
// se pasa el nombre cb como referencia a nuestra función callback
function requestName(userName, cb) {
  const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${userName}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json(); 
    })
    .then((json) => {
      cb(null, json); // <- aquí usamos la función callback con primer argumento: null
    })
    .catch(cb); // <- aquí usamos función callback que recibirá como único argumento el error
}
```

Notemos que `fetch` siempre devuelve una promesa, por lo tanto implementa `.then()` y `.catch()`, y esto no lo hemos modificado.

Para usar nuestra nueva función `requestName` usando `callback` se debe hacer el llamado de la siguiente forma:

```
// pasamos como argumento el nombre de la función callback que hemos creado
requestName('Nombre', showResponse);
```

Veamos un ejemplo funcional:

```js
// Función que servirá de callback
const showResponse = function(err, response) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(`El error es: ${err.message}`);
    return;
  }
  const extract = {
    name: response.name,
    location: response.location,
    bio: response.bio
  }
  console.log(extract);
}

// función que usa como argumento una función callback
function requestUser(userName,cb) {
  if(!userName) {
    const error = new ReferenceError('userName no puede ser nulo');
    return cb(error); // <- llamada a la función callback pasandole error como único parámetro
  }
  const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${userName}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
      return cb(null, json);
    })
    .catch(cb);
}

// Solicitud válida
requestUser('virtualkur2',showResponse);
// solicitud inválida (nótese que se muestra antes que la anterior)
requestUser(null,showResponse);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Espero que esto también te ayude a entender un poco más la forma de implementar funciones `callback` en tus métodos.

**Nota**

Esto simplemente es una forma muy básica de implementar una función `callback`, que no es más que una función que será llamada para ejecutarse en algún momento dentro del método en el cual fue pasada como argumento.

Puedes notar que la función inválida retorna primero que la función válida, aunque las mismas fueron llamadas en el orden inverso. Esto se debe que el método `fetch` es asíncrono.

Answer (score 1):

La función [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) no admite como segundo parámetro una función callback, siempre que trabajes con fetch será a través de la promesa que devuelve. Para usar callbacks tendrás que usar el clásico [`XmlHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). Ejemplo:

```
function requestName(userName){
  const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${userName}`;
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.response);
    }
  };
  request.open('GET', url);
  request.send();
}
```